# If $g(x_1,x_2)$ is analytic in $R^2$ and $g$ is a function of $\|x\|$ only. Is $h(\|x\|)=g(x_1,x_2)$ analytic in $\|x\|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $g(x_1,x_2)$ be a real-anaytic function of the pair $(x_1,x_2)$.

Also, suppose that $g(x_1,x_2)$ is only a fuction of $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} $.
That is 
\begin{align}
h(\|x\|)= g(x_1,x_2). 
\end{align}

Question:  Is $h(\|x\|)$ an analytic function of $\|x\|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because we can define 
$$h(t) = g(t,0)$$ an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then clearly 
$$h(\|x\|)= g(\|x\|,0) = g(x_1,x_2)$$
Note that $h$ is an even function, $h(-t)= h(t)$ for all $t$.

A related question is whether we have $g(x_1, x_2)=f(\|x\|^2)$ for some analytic function $f$ (equivalently, is $h(t)= f(t^2)$?)  One can find such a (unique such ) function $f$ analytic, but $f$ may only be defined on $(-\delta, \infty)$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you restate the related question you pointed out more formally? I just want to understand it better.

Comment: @Lisa: the question would be: if $h$ real analytic function is even, does there exist a real analytic function $f$ so that $h(t) = f(t^2)$?  Yes, but in general only defined on an interval $(-\delta, \infty)$, not on whole $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, take $h(t)= \frac{1}{1+t^2}$. Note that for complex analytic functions you do not have these problems.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. In  your  example, we have $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$ which is only analytic on $(-1,\infty)$, right?

Comment: @Lisa: Yes, excellent! This would not happen in  the complex domain.